# ReactJS: Passing props to map from parent component props are undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I have `<textarea>` elements created in a `map()` function and I am trying to get different values in each of these when rendering my component.

```
// Inside render method of ComponentA

fruits.map((fruit) => {
  return <textarea name={fruit.title} value={this.props.fruit.title} onChange={this.props.handleChange}
})
```

This sets `name={fruit.title}` correctly however, for the `value` prop, it gives me an error that title is `undefined`.

It seems like it literally takes it as `this.props.fruit` or something, rather than the value of `fruit.title`.

I'd like to pass different props of value so that I can use it in the following way from a parent component:

```
// State and rendered components inside ComponentB

state = {
  apple: '',
  orange: ''
}

handleChange = (e) => {
  const name = e.target.name;
  const value = e.target.value;
  this.setState(
     { [name]: value }
  );
}

<componentA
  handleChange={this.handleChange}
  apple={this.state.apple}
  orange={this.state.orange}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you require, consider the following implementation for `ComponentA`:

```
class ComponentA extends React.Component {

    render() {

        // Create a local array from apply and orange props
        const fruits = [ this.props.apple, this.props.orange ];

        // Map over the fruits and render each textarea as required
        return (<div>{ 
            fruits.map((fruit, index) => {
                return <textarea key={index}
                                 name={fruit} 
                                 value={fruit} 
                                 onChange={this.props.handleChange}></textarea>
            })</div>)    
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use the `fruits`? theres no title in the array.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: Why couldn't I know the way!! that's so simple but that's what exactly what I want! haha thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: Hey you're welcome! Glad we got there in the end :-)

Comment: Index is not first approach for key prop. It should be key={fruit}. index as a key is always second option

Comment: @HemadriDasari what if the array being mapped over looked like this? `[apple, orange, orange].map((item, index) => { /* item won't be unique seeing there are two references to the same orange object */ })`. In this case apple index = 0, orange index = 1, orange index = 2

Comment: Yes of values are not unique key should be index but you shouldn’t believe index as key it should be key={{"Key-"+index}} some string should be appended before index otherwise index is not concrete solution

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a case of a minor error in your mapping function. Try replacing:

`value={this.props.fruit.title}`

With:

`value={fruit.title}`

On the `<textarea>` element that you are returning from your `map()` callback.

Also since you are rendering textarea in the loop, ensure `onChange` is invoked correctly by replacing:

```
onChange={this.props.handleChange}
```

With:

```
onChange={e => this.props.handleChange(e)}
```

Also, consider adding a unique `key` prop to the `<textarea/>` to ensure correct rendering of the element list in your `map()` function like so:

```
fruits.map((fruit, index) => {
  return <textarea name={fruit.title} value={fruit.title} key={index} onChange={e => this.props.handleChange(e)}></textarea>
})
```

Comment: yeah but I'd like to the `{fruit.title}` to be props. like, `this.props.apple`, `this.props.orange` in the map function

Comment: So you want to access the `state` object, inside the `map()` function?

Comment: yep, in the component B for example

Comment: Oops sorry, yes!! the <SubmitForm/> must be component A in my example, my bad, will edit it now

Comment: @Dacre Denny I edited your answer to highlight two things 1. Restrict onChange call during render 2. Add unique key to textarea inside map. What do you think?

Comment: @HemadriDasari good observation with the `key` prop. I updated it to use the `index` which is guaranteed to be unique :-)

Comment: I didn’t get what u are talking about

Comment: @HemadriDasari the `key` prop should be unique for each item in the list. If you use a string value, you run the risk of duplicate `key` values in the rendered list. Using the `index` is a better option, seeing it is unique for each list item.

Comment: Sorry if my explanation isnt enough, I want `value={fruit.title}` to be props so that I can access it through `state` in the component B. so, let's say I don't use `map()` function. my code will be like `<textarea name="apple" value={this.props.apple}></textarea> <textarea name="orage" value={this.props.orage}></textarea>`

Comment: @MijeongWon ah ok - just provided a new answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54452835/8526705 does this help?

Comment: Nope index is not guaranteed to be unique. if OP thinks fruit name is always unique then key should be fruit else index I.e., also it should be key="Key-"+index

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
state = {
  fruits:[{title:'apple'},{title:'orange'}]
};

<SubmitForm
 handleChange={this.handleChange}
 fruits={[this.state.fruits]}
/>
```

Comment: This won’t resolve OP issue. Take a look at Dacre Denny answer